Construction of a simple function by open sets
A simple function $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ can be written as:
$$\phi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \chi_{E_k}(x)$$
where each $E_k$ is a measurable set and $\cup E_k = \mathbb{R}$ and $\chi_{E_k}$ is the characteristic function of $E_k$
This representation may not be unique. In particular if $E_i \cap E_j = \varnothing$ ($i \neq j$) it is called the standard representation of $\phi$
My question:
Suposse that $\phi$ is a simple function whose standard representation is $\phi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \chi_{E_k}(x)$. Could I choose whitout loss of generality another representation of $\phi$ such that each measurable set is open? that is:
$$ \phi(x) = \sum_{j=1}^m b_{j} \ \chi _{U_j}(x)$$
where $U_j$ is open
I know that the measure of each measurable set can be approximated by the measure of an open set that contains the original set. So is there a way to affirm that there exists a representation of $\phi$ by open sets?

No, this can't be done for arbitrary simple functions. Let $\mathbb{J}=\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Let $\phi=\chi_{\mathbb{J}}$. Let $U_1,\ldots, U_m$ be open sets. Note that for each $i$, $\partial U_i$ is closed and nowhere dense (has no interior points). Then $\cup_{i=1}^m \partial U_i$ is closed and nowhere dense, and therefore of first category in $\mathbb{R}$. By the Baire category theorem, $\mathbb{J}\setminus \cup_{i=1}^m \partial U_i\neq \varnothing$.  Pick $x\in \mathbb{J}\setminus \cup_{i=1}^m \partial U_i$ and note that, for each $1\leqslant i\leqslant m$, either $x\in U_i$ or $x\in \text{int}(\mathbb{R}\setminus U_i)$, where for a set $C$, $\text{int}(C)$ denotes the interior of $C$. Partition $\{1,\ldots, m\}$ into two sets $A,B$ so that $x\in U_i$ for all $i\in A$ and $x\in \text{int}(\mathbb{R}\setminus U_i)$ for all $i\in B$.  Since each $U_i$ and $\text{int}(\mathbb{R}\setminus U_i)$ are open, there exists $r>0$ such that $$(x-r,x+r)\subset U_i$$ for all $i\in A$ and $$(x-r,x+r)\subset \text{int}(\mathbb{R}\setminus U_i)\subset \mathbb{R}\setminus U_i$$ for all $i\in B$. Then for any scalars $b_1,\ldots, b_m$, if $\psi=\sum_{i=1}^m b_i\chi_{U_i}$, $\psi(y)=\sum_{i\in A}b_i$ for all $y\in (x-r,x+r)$. So $\psi$ is constant on some interval, while $\chi_{\mathbb{J}}$ is not constant on any interval.
